# How to get the result of a monogdb populated items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a file model referencing a note model with the note referencing a question model.

A file can have many notes and different notes can have many questions, how can I query a file by its ID in MongoDB to return all the questions under all notes which are under a file.

File--->Notes--->Questions

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const fileSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Please add a title'],
            trim: true,
        },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
        notes: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Note',
            },
        ],
       
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
    },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('File', fileSchema);


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const noteSchema = new Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Please add a title'],
            trim: true,
        },
       
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
       
        questions: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Question',
            },
        ],
      
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to Mongoose's example of [Populating across multiple levels](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)

> Say you have a user schema which keeps track of the user's friends.
>
> ```
> const userSchema = new Schema({
>  name: String,
>  friends: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
> });
> ```
>
> Populate lets you get a list of a user's friends, but what if you also wanted a user's friends of friends? Specify the populate option to tell mongoose to populate the friends array of all the user's friends:
>
> ```
> User.
>   findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
>   populate({
>     path: 'friends',
>     // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
>     populate: { path: 'friends' }
>   });
> ```

In your case it may look like this:

```
File
  .findById(id)
  .populate({
    path: 'notes',
    populate: { path: 'questions' }
  });
```